# How to use check ansible task result from inside a loop made with_items?

Tags: ansible

Imagine this Ansible code that is supposed to set the task as failed only when the command returns a value different than 0 or 1.

```
- shell: some-command
  register: result
  failed_when: result.rc not in [0, 1] or 'err' in result.stdout_lines
```

How it would look the variant that does use a with_items loop? As you probably know for these result structure would contain a `results` dictionary which stores the results of each item.

Sadly for us, we want to decide the failed status by looking at all.

```
- shell: "{{ item }}"
  register: result
  failed_when: ????
  with_items:
  - ls
  - df
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-issue. Use the same condition as in your first example:

```
- shell: "{{ item }}"
  register: result
  failed_when: result.rc not in [0, 1] or 'err' in result.stdout_lines
  with_items:
  - ls
  - df
```

> As you probably know for these result structure would contain a `results` dictionary which stores the results of each item.

Except that this structure is created after the execution and is accessible from subsequent tasks, not from inside the loop.

Comment: @techrag Does this mean that the `result` variable accessible to failed_when or to ignore_errors is not the same as the one restered in the end? This would clearly be a bit confusing because it means that result has rc member inside the failed_when, but this no longer exists after the task had run.